# Elvis operator in GString in Groovy

Tags: groovy, closures, gstring

```
String someMethod(def columnOne, int number, columnName){
     return columnOne + '-' + number + "${ -> (columnName == '') ?: '-' + columnName}"
}
```

and when I call it with:

```
someMethod('one', 2, '')
```

I get the following result:

```
one-2true
```

Why the closure returns `true` but not the `''` or `-somehting`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the elvis here but the regular ternary, like this:

```
(columnName ? '-'+columnName : '')
```

Elvis is short for `x ?: y` => `x ? x : y` and the result of `columnName==''` then simply is `true` and this will print.

Answer (score 1):

Make full use the groovy's GString. String concatenation is expensive.

```
return "$columnOne-$number${columnName ? '-' + columnName : ''}"
```